# Mixture of ASP.NET Core and .NET 4.7.2 makes Visual Studio forget to copy content files to dependent project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, .net-core

Here's an odd situation we encountered:

Project A is an ASP.NET Core 1.1 application. We need to reference some nuget packages that don't target any netcore* frameworks, so we changed the target framework to net472 by editing the csproj file. This project works fine.

Project B is a NUnit project. It's a traditional .NET framework test library (csproj file starts off with `<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" (etc..)`. Project B references project A to unit test files in project A.

Project A has a couple of data files that need to be copied to its target directory to work, in particular `appsettings.json`. This file is required by the Startup.cs file. This is standard ASP.NET core stuff, as I understand it. The properties on the file are both set as `Content` and `Copy always`.

Here's the weird part:

- When building in Visual Studio, the `appsettings.json` file is not copied to the output folder of the unit test project. This causes unit tests to fail with messages like `The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional.`
- When building with MSBuild from the command line, the `appsettings.json` file is copied to the target directory for the unit test project as expected.

It's like there's something about the project configuration that has caused Visual Studio to forget to copy content files. Because msbuild behaves the way I expect, it make me think this is a bug in the Visual Studio build process. But maybe there is something we could change in the project configuration to fix this?

We have worked around this issue by linking the appsettings.json file in the unit test project. But we have some other projects with this issue and I'd like to be sure we have the right fix.

Edit: forgot to mention, I am running Visual Studio 2017 15.8.4 on Windows 10. A colleague is working on Windows 7 with the same version of Visual Studio and she doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Same issue here since I've updated VS in 15.8.4. Asp.net Core project and MSTest V2 project. Running integration tests with TestServer failed since app.settings is no longer copied to the test project output. Compiling with msbuild copy the appsetting.